# How is it possible to check if JOptionPane is visible?

Tags: java, visible, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane option dialog which is called in my application in case there is an invalid file. It then takes input for the right file.

This is fine as long as the application is running in a GUI environment.

**Requirement**
In the case of a headless server, I need to first verify if the option pane is visible. If it is invisible, I need to display the error on the command line and exit.

How do I achieve this?
Is there a way to check if JOptionPane is visible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is sufficient to check if you are headless. You can do so by the method [`GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#isHeadless%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help you but I'm suggesting the use of `Component.isShowing()` method.